# Copy data from a DataGrip installation to another

Tags: postgresql, dump, datagrip

I've two different pc I use to code and I've inserted data just on the laptop, where DataGrip is installed. Now I would want to clone data on the desktop where I've installed DataGrip and set the Postgres driver and database.
Which is the faster way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Am I right that you want to copy data between databases?

Comment: Exactly. Between to equal databases.

Comment: DataGrip now cannot do this, but what about dump/restore tools? What database do you use?

Comment: I use Postgres and I've also installed pgAdmin, but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

In DataGrip there are dump/restore tools for PostgreSQL

To dump the objects, use the Dump with… context menu option. Restore tools for MySQL and PostgreSQL also can be accessed from the context menu. In the case of PostgreSQL, the restore operation can be done with pg_dump or psql: there is a way to choose in the Restore dialog.

[image]